# Mui custom table sizes - custom theme

Tags: typescript, material-ui

Using material UI I have successfully added a couple of extra sizes for the Table size prop with this declaration:

```
declare module '@mui/material' {
  interface TablePropsSizeOverrides {
    relaxed: true
    large: true
  }
}
```

I can now use these 2 extra sizes like so `<Table size="relaxed" />`

But I cannot select the classes in theme like I can for the default small|medium. How can I let typescript know about these other classes?:

```
const materialTheme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiTableCell: {
      styleOverrides: {
        sizeSmall: {
          padding: '7px 16px', // roughly height 40
        },
        sizeRelaxed: {
          padding: '16px'
        }
      },
    },
  },
```

`'sizeRelaxed' does not exist in type 'Partial<OverridesStyleRules<keyof TableCellClasses, "MuiTableCell", Omit<Theme, "components">>>`

Answer (score 0):

Following your code above, you can augment the keys of `TableCellClasses`, to add your custom sizes, with:

```
declare module '@mui/material' {
  interface TablePropsSizeOverrides {
    relaxed: true
    large: true
  }

  // Addition

  // Represents the classes applied to the individual table cells
  // when the custom TablePropsSizeOverrides values are set
  interface TableCellClasses {
    sizeRelaxed: true;
    sizeLarge: true;
  }

  // End of addition
}
```

Working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-table-extended-sizes-g6pq9n?file=/Demo.tsx